# Arkanoid in C#, help needed

Tags: c#

I have searched on web, but dint find any tips how to do it. IDE to be used in Microsoft Visual Studio. What project type must I choose to make Arkanoid game?

Answer (score 3):

Try Microsoft's XNA Framework. Here are some links:

[XNA on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA)
[Main Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpfull too...

[2d Game Tutorial C#](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/tutorial/2dgame/getting_started)

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to deploy this game?

1. Standalone exe? -> Windows Forms / WPF
2. Browser?

   2.1 Html only -> Web Forms / MVC

   2.2 Rich -> Silverlight